# NoClassDefFoundError while calling class of another project

Tags: jakarta-ee, runtime-error

I have two projects , 
i) java se that implements database connectivity and other database related manipulation ,
ii) java web project (I am learning servlet programming),which has a servlet class that asks for an employee id and prints employee details.
Second project uses classes from 1st project. 
I have exported first project as .jar and imported it in second project. However , I am getting NoClassDefFound error while calling classes from 1st project. 
How to resolve it ?

Comment: Make sure that jar file is in the classpath.

Comment: i have done that .. but the error is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the your application1.jar file to the class path of the web application? If your second application is deployed as a .war file you can place your application1.jar file in applicatin2.war/WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: yes I have already added application1.jar file to the classpath